# Minipage not finding width argument

Tags: minipage

The following code is producing an error:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp!]
\subfloat{
    \begin{minipage}[c][Structured Mesh]{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{ch-SmallStrain/Graphics/Structured}
    \end{minipage}}
\subfloat{
    \begin{minipage}[c][Unstructured Mesh]{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{ch-SmallStrain/Graphics/Unstructured}
    \end{minipage}}
\\
\subfloat{
    \begin{minipage}[c][Structured Mesh, zoomed to red box shown above]{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{ch-SmallStrain/Graphics/StructuredCloseup}
    \end{minipage}}
\subfloat{
    \begin{minipage}[c][Unstructured Mesh, zoomed to red box shown above]{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{ch-SmallStrain/Graphics/UnstructuredCloseup}
    \end{minipage}}
    \caption{Meshes for the Shearing example\label{fig:Meshes-for-the}}
\end{figure}
```

The error is:

> ! Missing number, treated as zero.
>    
>                      S
>   l.634         \end{minipage}}

which occurs at each `\end{minipage}`. This seems to me like the width arguments `{0.5\textwidth}` are not being recognized, and indeed the error goes away if I remove the optional arguments in the `[]`. Is there a way to fix this error while keeping the optional arguments?

Edit:

I forgot to mention that I am using the subfig package and the second optional argument is supposed to be the caption of the subfigure.

Comment: what do you want the `[Unstructured Mesh]` argument to do? (minipage doesn't have an argument that takes text in that way). Without a hint on the intended result hard to suggest how to correct the code.

Comment: I think you should read a bit about [`minipage`](http://svn.gna.org/viewcvs/*checkout*/latexrefman/trunk/latex2e.html#minipage) and its parameters.

Comment: Please edit your example to be a complete small document that shows the problem (a complete small document showing all packages used is always preferable to a fragment)

Answer (score 5):

I assume you intend the second argument in brackets following `\begin{minipage}` to act as the subfloat's caption. If that's your objective, you should place the argument immediately after `\subfloat` rather than after `\begin{minipage}`.

Note that the `minipage` environment can take up to three optional arguments -- an "outer" vertical alignment indicator, which can be `t` for `top`, `c` for `center`, and `b` for bottom; a height variable (a TeX "length" entity); and an "inner" position indicator -- and *two mandatory arguments*: a length variable to set the intended width of the environment and the actual contents of the minipage, both to be placed in curly braces.

Another observation: Unless there's a very good reason for making the subfloat graphs have different widths, you may just want to give all four the *same width*. This may be achieved by setting the option `width=\linewidth` when executing `\includegraphics`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} %leave off the 'demo' option in your real document
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\subfloat[Structured Mesh]{%
  \begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{ch-SmallStrain/Graphics/Structured}
  \end{minipage}}
\hspace{\fill} % induce horizontal separation
\subfloat[Unstructured Mesh]{%
  \begin{minipage}[c]{0.48\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{ch-SmallStrain/Graphics/Unstructured}
  \end{minipage}}

\subfloat[Structured Mesh, zoomed to red box shown above]{%
  \begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth}  
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{ch-SmallStrain/Graphics/StructuredCloseup}
  \end{minipage}}
\hspace{\fill} % induce horizontal separation
\subfloat[Unstructured Mesh, zoomed to red box shown above]{%
  \begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{ch-SmallStrain/Graphics/UnstructuredCloseup}
  \end{minipage}}
\caption{Meshes for the Shearing example\label{fig:Meshes-for-the}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: good answer except minipage does take optional argument in that position but it is the _height_ which is why you get a missing number primitive TeX error if you put text there as the argument has to be a length.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Thanks, I'll fix it right away.

Comment: "one optional argument" - it takes three: `[outer pos][height][inner pos]` the OP was putting the caption in the `[height]` argument.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Arrgh, thanks! (I must be particularly distracted tonight!!) Let me fix this.

Comment: @Mico - why is the `minipage` environment required ? You can make the same figure only using  the `subfloat` only...

Comment: @Nicolas - I guess we don't know what the vertical dimensions of the OP's real image files are. If their heights aren't the same, then using `minipage` environments provides extra options for achieving a satisfactory positioning of the various subfloat elements.

Answer (score 1):

As previously suggested, if you intend to use the `minipage` environment to set the `captions` of the sufigures, the `subfloat` itself can do it and you may simply remove all the `minipages` in the figure.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} %leave off the 'demo' option in your real document

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \subfloat[Structured Mesh]{%
        \includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{ch-SmallStrain/Graphics/Structured}
    }
    \hfill % induce horizontal separation
    \subfloat[Unstructured Mesh]{%
        \includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{ch-SmallStrain/Graphics/Unstructured}
    }

    \subfloat[Structured Mesh, zoomed to red box shown above]{%  
        \includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{ch-SmallStrain/Graphics/StructuredCloseup}
    }
    \hfill % induce horizontal separation
    \subfloat[Unstructured Mesh, zoomed to red box shown above]{%
        \includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{ch-SmallStrain/Graphics/UnstructuredCloseup}
    }
    \caption{Meshes for the Shearing example\label{fig:Meshes-for-the}}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

You can adjust the `width` of each figure within the `includegraphics` command.

[image: output]